# How to Query Updated Post in WordPress

Tags: wp-query

I have seen some website which are showing the updated post. How can I query updated post from database.

please help me

thank's

Comment: Do you mean a post that was updated, like a revision

Comment: yes I mean the old post which I updated now. And want to display them. which query I can use

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this query from [perishablepress.com](http://perishablepress.com/stupid-wordpress-tricks/) to get post revisions.

```
<?php 

$today  = current_time('mysql', 1);
$number = 5; // number of posts

if($recentposts = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT ID, post_title FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE post_status = 'publish' AND post_modified_gmt < '$today' ORDER BY post_modified_gmt DESC LIMIT $number")):

?>

<h2><?php _e('Recently Updated'); ?></h2>
<ul>
<?php

foreach($recentposts as $post) {

    if($post->post_title == '') $post->post_title = sprintf(__('Post #%s'), $post->ID);
    echo '<li><a href="'.get_permalink($post->ID).'">'.the_title().'</a></li>';

} ?>
</ul>

<?php endif; ?>
```

This queries the database according to the `post_modified_gmt` time of a post, and then also ordered the returned posts according to `post_modified_gmt`

Comment: My pleasure, glad I could help